# Connect to two different networks on two interfaces

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-10

I have two different networks at home - one is my regular home network and another is a VPN hardware device tunneling to the work network. Is there a way to configure my laptop to be connected to both networks at the same time - one via wifi and another via ethernet cable? The ultimate goal is to have the laptop on the VPN connection, but also being able to access it from another computer that is on my home network.

The laptop is running Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a VPN software which allows to run so called split tunnel mode.
For example what you are looking for is not possible with the Cisco VPN.
Cisco VPN will force all the traffic via tunnel.
But there are other alternatives, below is a list of those that I know of and used.

- vpnc
- shrewsoft vpn

So if you have VPN client that allows you to run split tunnel - you don't need multiple NICs. You can just setup static routes on your laptop to access local network.

Comment: We are using some proprietary vpn client, I don't have any control over its configuration. I was just hoping that I could configure Windows to use both connections simultaneously.

Comment: See if you can add static host routes to hosts on your local network while connected to VPN. If you can and it works - means your client runs in split tunnel mode. If static route does nothing - means your client is forcing all traffic via tunnel. The fact that you are using proprietary VPN client doesn't mean that you can't replace it with open source client. You just need to know certain settings of VPN connection. Check with your IT department, perhaps they can help.